# Updating the reference data for an existing geocode service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, geocoding, rest

I created an address locator in an ArcSDE gdb, based on data stored in a point feature class in the same SDE gdb. I then shared the locator as a geocode service and am consuming it in a Silverlight app. All of this works perfectly.

I have now updated my reference data in the point feature class, and rebuilt the locator. Would I have to recreate the geocode service to access the updated reference data? I have been reading the extensive help on [registering data with ArcGIS Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_registering_your_data_with_the_server/015400000505000000/), and followed the tutorial on [publishing a geocode service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Publishing_a_geocode_service/00250000004p000000/), but it appears that the locator data has been copied over to the server, even though the SDE gdb is accessible to it.

I tried replacing the service, but it wouldn't let me (had to specify a new name). When I then tried connect to the second geocoding service, it said connection failed (even though it is set up the same way as the original service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it shouldn't be necessary, the geocode service had to be restarted before the updated data reflected. There was no need to recreate the entire service.